# Get yesterday from simpledataformat

Tags: android, simpledateformat

It's my code for getting today to long.
Can I get yesterday by using this code?

```
SimpleDateFormat date_0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
Date date_1 = new Date();
long date_t = Long.valueOf(date_0.format(date_1));
```

**EDIT>**
I solve with this

```
SimpleDateFormat date_0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
Date date_1 = new Date();
long date_t = Long.valueOf(date_0.format(date_1));
long date_2 = date_1.getTime();
Date yesterday = new Date(date_2 -= 86400000);
long date_y = Long.valueOf(date_0.format(yesterday));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the current date, and subtract 86400000 milliseconds (equivalent to one day).

```
           SimpleDateFormat date_0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
           Date date_1 = new Date();
           long date_t = date_1.getTime();
           date_t -= 86400000;
           Date yesterday = new Date(date_t);
           System.out.println("Yesterday's Date: " + date_0.format(yesterday));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat date_0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
Date date_1 = new Date();
date_1.setDate(date_1.getDay()-1);
long date_t = Long.valueOf(date_0.format(date_1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat date_0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // this is default system date
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);    // minus date to previous day 
long date_t = Long.valueOf(date_0.format(calendar.getTime())); // convert into long
System.out.println(date_0.format(calendar.getTime())); // system print 151110
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). The design allows for multiple calendar systems, while still providing a simple API.

```
private DateTime getPreviousDateAndTime(int previousCount){
   DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000000000");
   DateTime now = new DateTime();
   DateTime expectedDate = now.minusDays(previousCount);
   return expectedDate;
}
```

Add the following dependency to **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple..

```
private Calendar calendar;

  public void getPreviousDay() {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    }
```